# Is there a way to create a shortlink for websites to map, say, http://r/ to http://reddit.com ?

Tags: networking, dns

Basically I am looking for a way to make custom self-contained shortlinks so that if I wanted to, I could go into Chrome and type r/food and have it take me to reddit.com/r/food or au/ and have it take me to askubuntu.com

Is there any reasonable way to do this that you know of? I know some companies I have worked for have internal methods for this but I have yet to find a way to do it locally.

Ideally, DNS would still be in effect such that I don't have to map au/ to askubuntu's IP address.

Comment: Check out the hosts file: `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: @mikewhatever   
  
That was the first thing I tried. But adding a line that looks like this:   

 

http://au askubuntu.com  
  
  
does not work